# how to use Java validator annotations from constructor?

Tags: java, spring, validation, bean-validation

I have value object that holds `String`. That String is subject to some restrictions (length, allowed characters, etc).

I would like to use Java or Spring validation API for validating my object.
I would like to validate my domain object at creation time (in constructor).

Sample code that realises that (validates `this` using validation API):

```
void validate() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Msisdn>> violations = localValidatorFactoryBean.getValidator().validate(this);
        if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ConstraintViolationException(violations);
        }
    }
```

I do not know how to get instance of `javax.validation.Validator` from constructor.

In Spring-managed code (service) I could just `@Autowire` instance of `javax.validation.Validator` 
 or `org.springframework.validation.Validator` and it works.

But how to make it work outside of Spring-managed code (in constructor of value object, that stands on his own)?

I know that I can write validation rules using ifs, but validation annotations makes code much simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Hibernate Validator documentation describes how to get instance of javax.validation.Validator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/chapter-bean-constraints.html#section-obtaining-validator)

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
```

But it is not suitable to build `ValidatorFactory` in constructor. It is time-consuming operation. Maybe using cached reference in thrad-local would help, but I do not like that increased complexity.

Finally, I have decided to write validation rules for my value objects using
[Guava Preconditions](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/PreconditionsExplained)

```
 Preconditions.checkNotNull(value, "value cannot be null");
```